# How to redirect to TOP from iframe when JavaScript is disabled?

Tags: iframe

JavaScript seems to be the only solution that I can find to bust out of an iFame and open a link in the top window. But what if JavaScript is disabled?

Without JavaScript, is there a way to redirect the main page from within the iFrame?

Comment: Set the right headers and *no one* (on any modern browser) can frame your site if you don't want them to. https://pragmaticwebsecurity.com/articles/securitypolicies/preventing-framing-with-policies.html

Comment: @ceejayoz - that is not applicable. Our clients use an iFrame on their web pages that displays a page from our website... that is allowed.